# .net core 8.0 console application to groupby my list using 4 columns

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-8, pnp-core-sdk

I have 2 SharePoint lists

1. Assets list, with these fields:-

- ID
- MediumID

2. WorkOrders list, with these fields:-

- ID
- WorkOrderStatus
- WorkOrderType
- TechnicianName
- AssetID

and i am getting the lists items using pnp core sdk inside the below .net core 8.0 console application, as follow:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PnP.Core.Auth;
using PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint;
using PnP.Core.QueryModel;
using PnP.Core.Services;
using PnP.Core.Services.Builder.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tenantId = "***";
            var clientId = "****8";
            var certificatePath = @"****";
            var certificatePassword = "*****";

            // Initialize a new service collection
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            // Load the certificate
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            // Configure logging
            serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                 builder.AddConsole();
             });

            // Add and configure PnP Core SDK
            serviceCollection.AddPnPCore(options =>
            {
                options.PnPContext.GraphFirst = true; // Set true if you prefer to use Graph over CSOM when possible
                                                      // options.HttpRequests.UserAgent = "ISV|Contoso|ProductX";
                options.Sites.Add("SiteToWorkWith", new PnPCoreSiteOptions
                {
                    SiteUrl = "https://*******.sharepoint.com/sites/S****-PPM",
                    AuthenticationProvider = new X509CertificateAuthenticationProvider(clientId, tenantId, certificate)
                });
            });

            int i = 0;
            // Build the service provider
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Use the service provider to get the IPnPContextFactory instance
            var pnpContextFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPnPContextFactory>();

            // Now you can use the IPnPContextFactory to get a PnPContext and perform operations
            var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SiteToWorkWith");
            // Assume the fields where not yet loaded, so loading them with the list
            var workOrderList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Work Orders", p => p.Title,
                                                                 p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                               p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                               p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                               p => p.Title));

            // Build a query that only returns the Title field for the first 20 items where the Title field starts with "Item1"
            string viewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                    <ViewFields>
                      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                      <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                      <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                        <FieldRef Name='WorkOrderStatus' />
                        <FieldRef Name='WorkOrderType' />
                        <FieldRef Name='TechnicianName' />
                        <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                        <FieldRef Name='AssetID' />
                    </ViewFields>
                    <Query>
<Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
        <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
    </Eq>
                    </Query>
                   </View>";

            // Load all the needed data using paged requests
            bool paging = true;
            string nextPage = null;
            while (paging)
            {
                var output = await workOrderList.LoadListDataAsStreamAsync(new RenderListDataOptions()
                {
                    ViewXml = viewXml,
                    RenderOptions = RenderListDataOptionsFlags.ListData,
                    Paging = nextPage ?? null,
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (output.ContainsKey("NextHref"))
                {
                    nextPage = output["NextHref"].ToString().Substring(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    paging = false;
                }
            }

            // Iterate over the retrieved list items
            foreach (var listItem in workOrderList.Items.AsRequested())
            {
                // Do something with the list item
                Console.WriteLine(listItem["AssetID"]);
            }

            //var kpipertechreport = workOrderList.Items.AsRequested().GroupBy("TechnicianName");


            var assetsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Assets", p => p.Title,
                                                                  p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                                p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                                p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                                p => p.Title));
            string viewXml2 = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
         <ViewFields>
           <FieldRef Name='Title' />
           <FieldRef Name='Created' />
           <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
 <FieldRef Name='MediumID' />
         </ViewFields>
         <Query>
         </Query>
        </View>";

            // Load all the needed data using paged requests
            bool paging2 = true;
            string nextPage2 = null;
            while (paging2)
            {
                var output = await assetsList.LoadListDataAsStreamAsync(new RenderListDataOptions()
                {
                    ViewXml = viewXml2,
                    RenderOptions = RenderListDataOptionsFlags.ListData,
                    Paging = nextPage ?? null,
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (output.ContainsKey("NextHref"))
                {
                    nextPage2 = output["NextHref"].ToString().Substring(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    paging2 = false;
                }


            }


            var workOrderReport = workOrderList.Items.AsRequested()
                // First, map each work order to its corresponding MediumID from the assets list
                .Select(wo => new
                {
                    TechnicianName = wo["TechnicianName"],
                    WorkOrderStatus = wo["WorkOrderStatus"],
                    Created = DateTime.Parse(wo["Created"].ToString()),
                      MediumID = (wo["AssetID"]!=null && assetsList.Items.AsRequested().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.ToString() == wo["AssetID"].ToString()) != null ? assetsList.Items.AsRequested().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.ToString() == wo["AssetID"].ToString())?["MediumID"]: string.Empty)
                })
                // Group by TechnicianName, then by Year, then by Month, then by MediumID
                .GroupBy(wo => wo.TechnicianName)
                .Select(groupByTechnician => new
                {
                    Technician = groupByTechnician.Key,
                    YearlyReport = groupByTechnician
                        .GroupBy(wo => wo.Created.Year)
                        .Select(groupByYear => new
                        {
                            Year = groupByYear.Key,
                            MonthlyReport = groupByYear
                                .GroupBy(wo => wo.Created.Month)
                                .Select(groupByMonth => new
                                {
                                    Month = groupByMonth.Key,
                                    MediumReports = groupByMonth
                                        .GroupBy(wo => wo.MediumID)
                                        .Select(groupByMedium => new
                                        {
                                            MediumID = groupByMedium.Key,
                                            TotalCount = groupByMedium.Count(),
                                            DoneCount = groupByMedium.Count(wo => wo.WorkOrderStatus == "Done")
                                        })
                                })
                        })
                });
            foreach (var kpireport in workOrderReport)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(kpireport.Technician.ToString());


            }
            // Ensure to dispose the context
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

now i want to build a report, which shows the number of work orders which have their status as Done and the overall total number of work order for each technician within each year and within each month and within each mediumID..but the `workOrderReport` will contain items count equals to the work orders count, so seems my code is not doing any grouping. can anyone advice why my code is failing?

Thanks

Comment: wow my question has been closed.. i can not see any relation between my question and the one marked as duplicate!!

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, how do you found that this is duplicate of NullReferenceException?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i do not know either.. but please correct the reference to his username so he can get your comment more clearer.. thanks